# SonarQube: Error while running build-wrapper

Tags: sonarqube, sonar-runner

Trying to run build-wrapper as suggested here http://docs.sonarqube.org/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=3080359

but its giving me error "The system cannot find the file specified"

`C:\Users\<path>>build-wrapper.exe --out-dir build_dir msbuild
foo.sln /t:Rebuild
Could not execute msbuild foo.sln /t:Rebuild: The system cannot f
ind the file specified.`

`C:\Users\<path>>build-wrapper.exe --out-dir build_dir msbuild
fooapp.vcprojx /t:Rebuild
Could not execute msbuild fooapp.vcprojx /t:Rebuild: The system cannot f
ind the file specified.`

Comment: What happens if you run `msbuild foo.sln /t:Rebuild` from the same directory ?

Comment: The build-wrapper targets the commercial C/C++/Objective-C plugin, so you should contact the commercial support if you want to get help => http://www.sonarsource.com/get-contact/

Comment: And obviously please close/delete your question as nobody will be able to help you on Stackoverflow on this topic.

Answer (score 0):

Set the path of "MsBuild.exe" to your path and then rerun. You may find MSBUild.exe under folder C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild.